# html page problem in the visual studio code

Tags: javascript, html

when i run my code in VS (macbook) it appear This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect. + http://localhost:8080/
how i can solve this problem and how to run in Firefox instead of Chrome

give me solution of this problem and how to run my code in Firefox

Comment: Helps to have a local webserver installed and running.

Comment: e.g. `XAMPP` or a `Live Server` extension in VSC.